# Lombok javafx properties

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8, lombok

I'm trying to use Lombok in combination with JavaFX properties:

```
@Data
public class Country {
    private SimpleIntegerProperty id = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
    private SimpleStringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();
}
```

This generates getters and setters for the Properties itself:

- getId(): SimpleIntegerProperty
- setId(SimpleIntegerProperty id)
- getName: SimpleStringProperty
- setName(SimpleStringProperty name)
- ...

However, I would expect(/like) this in JavaFX:

- getId(): int
- setId(int id)
- getIdProperty(): SimpleIntegerProperty
- getName(): String
- setName(String name)
- getNameProperty(): SimpleStringProperty
- ...

Is this supported in Lombok? I don't find much information about Lombok in combination with JavaFX (or I must be searching wrong). I'm not really familiar with Lombok yet, so apologies if this is a basic question.

Comment: I don't know lombok, but I strongly suspect the answer is "no". Lombok is designed to replace boiler-plate code: the JavaFX properties pattern doesn't match the boiler plate it replaces. Note that tools like e(fx)clipse provide a more "traditional" code generation approach that works with JavaFX (I understand that is different to what you are asking though).

Comment: @James_D thanks for your response, I was afraid that was gonna be the case. I just hoped there was a workaround or an extra plugin or something like that :) Could you add your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no support, see [issue 521](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/521). I'm afraid, there's nothing beside the issue and [an discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/project-lombok/TN6GTVJNJqU).